# Google Maps: Find all zip codes along route

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Given two locations you can calculate a route in Google Maps.

1. Is it possible to find all zip codes along the route?
2. Given a zip code, can I expand the area easily with a 10 km radius and find all zip codes in that area?

What methods should I use to get this information? Tutorials are welcome. I don't need a complete working solution, although if one is available that would be really nice.

Answer (score 2):

You need a data source containing the zipcode (ZCTA) polygons.  One possible source is [this FusionTable](http://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=1499916).

[proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_ZipcodesAlongRoute_configurable.html?from=Mission%20Vjieo,CA&to=Irvine,CA&submit=)

[proof of concept showing ZCTA polygons](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_ZipcodesAlongRoute_configurableA.html?from=New%20York,%20NY&to=Newark,%20NJ&submit=)

Note: since it queries for the zip code at *every* point along the route, it will take longer to finish the longer the route is.

code that performs the query (using the Google Visualization API):

```
function queryForZip(latlng) {
  //set the query using the current latlng
  var queryStr = "SELECT geometry, ZIP, latitude, longitude FROM "+ tableid + " WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG"+latlng+",1))";   
  var queryText = encodeURIComponent(queryStr);
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq='  + queryText);

  //set the callback function
  query.send(addZipCode);
}  

function addZipCode(response) {
if (!response) {
  alert('no response');
  return;
}
if (response.isError()) {
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += 'Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage()+"<br>";
  return;
} 
  FTresponse = response;
  //for more information on the response object, see the documentation
  //http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#QueryResponse
  numRows = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
  numCols = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns();
  for(i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
      var zip = response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 1);
      var zipStr = zip.toString()
      if (!zipcodes[zipStr]) {
        zipcodes[zipStr] = zipStr;
        document.getElementById('zipcodes').innerHTML += zipStr+"<br>";
      }
  }
}
```